# Jquery spinner doesn't work after closing Dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, spinner

I'm facing a problem which occurs after closing a dilog, the spinners in my page don't work anymore. 
On loading my page, all spinners work, but after openning a dialog and closing it, the spinners don't work.

I have in my page aspx spinners (about 10), and div  used as dialog, the dialog open when an image is clicked

I'm using Jquery:  spinner, dialog

Asp.net Jquery

```
//dialog
$("#Div_Com").dialog({

            autoOpen: false,
            width: 'auto',
            modal: true,
            autoResize: true,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "blind",
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo($("#form1"));
            }
        });

//Open dialog
$('#img_open_click').live('click', function () {


            $("#Div_Com').dialog('open');
        });

//Close dialog
$('#img_Close_click').live('click', function () {
            $("#Div_Com').dialog(close);
        });

//Spinner
 $("#Spinner").spinner({
                min: -7, max: 0,
                spin: function (event, ui) {
                    alert('ok');
                    if ($("#Spinner").spinner("value") < ui.value) { alert('1'); }
                    else if ($("#Spinner").spinner("value") > ui.value) { alert('2'); }
                    else { };
                }
            });

ASPX
 // spinner declaration
  < asp:TextBox ID="Spinner"  Text="0" runat="server" style="text-align:center;"         BackColor="#D7ECFA" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox> '

//Image to open dialog
      < img id="img_open_click" src="../App_Themes/oxygene/img/picto_stylo.png" alt="" />

//Div as dialog
   < div id="Div_Com" class="hide" >                                         
   < asp:TextBox ID="Com_Multi" runat="server" BackColor="#D7ECFA" Rows="9"    TextMode="MultiLine" Width="90%" Height="90%" ></asp:TextBox>

< img  src="../App_Themes/oxygene/img/button_cancel.jpg" alt="" id="img_Close_click"/>
 < /div>
```

Comment: Posting the relevant sections of your code would be useful.

Comment: it would be nice and helpful if you prepare a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: #Spinner... do you have ALL spinners using the same ID ?

Comment: I've seen the problem before.  The way I solved it was when you display the spinner again, reset the src to the image again.